# JsonArrayRequest in Volley does not pass any value to the ListView

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to use Volley for my project and I used `JsonArrayRequest()` to get JSON array encoded from PHP and adapt it on `ListView`. I have followed a tutorial from this page:
https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

My app was crashed and below was the error.

```
2019-03-18 15:34:51.706 14999-14999/com.example.smartparkingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smartparkingapp, PID: 14999
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.app.Activity.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.smartparkingapp.adapter.CarListAdapter.getView(CarListAdapter.java:48)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3180)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2197)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:824)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:885)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1924)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2952)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:966)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6440)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3043)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2730)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1859)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8087)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
2019-03-18 15:34:51.707 14999-14999/com.example.smartparkingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Here is my PHP code, where **car_list.php** require connection from **smart_parking_connect.php** and **smart_parking_connect.php** contain database variables.

**smart_parking_config.php**

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "garuda96");
define("DB_DATABASE", "mydb");

?>
```

**smart_parking_connect.php**

```
<?php

class Connect {
    public $conn;

    //connecting to database
    function Connect() {
        require_once('smart_parking_config.php');

        //connecting to mysql database
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        //return database object
        return $this->conn; 
    }  
}?>
```

**car_list.php**

```
<?php

    require_once('smart_parking_connect.php');

    $connect = new Connect();

    $conn = $connect->conn;

    if($conn){

            $carResult = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT carLicense, idCustomer FROM Car");

            while($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($carResult)){
                $car[] = array('idCustomer' => $obj->idCustomer, 'carLicense' => $obj->carLicense);
            }

            echo json_encode($car);

    } else {
        $response['success'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "Connection failure";
        echo json_encode($response);

    }

?>
```

On the Android side, i have created 3 fragments for `MainActivity.java` and I used the `JsonArrayRequest()` inside 'HomeFragment.java'. The other Fragment is working smoothly.

**HomeFragment.java** *(to simplify it, I have removed all of the import)*

```
package com.example.smartparkingapp;    

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String carListURL = Variable.connstr + "car_list.php";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    private CarListAdapter carListAdapter;
    private RequestQueue queue;

    private  FloatingActionButton assignCarButton;
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private TextView testTextView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    private ListView carListView;
    private SharedPreferencesConfig preferencesConfig;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String name, idCustomer;

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        preferencesConfig = new SharedPreferencesConfig(getContext());

        assignCarButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.assignCarButton);
        logoutButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        testTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.testTextView);

        name = preferencesConfig.readUsername();
        nameTextView.setText(name);

        idCustomer = Integer.toString(preferencesConfig.readId());

        carListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.carList);
        carListAdapter = new CarListAdapter(this, carList);
        carListView.setAdapter(carListAdapter);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();    

        //Creating volley request obj
       JsonArrayRequest carReq = new JsonArrayRequest(carListURL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        //parsing JSON
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Car car = new Car();
                                car.setId(obj.getString("idCustomer"));
                                car.setCarPlate(obj.getString("carLicense"));

                                carList.add(car);
                                carListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(carReq);

                assignCarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        openDialog();
                    }
                });

            logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Logout(getActivity());
                }
            });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    public void openDialog() {
        NumberPlateDialog numberPlateDialog = new NumberPlateDialog();
        numberPlateDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Number Plate Dialog");
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (progressDialog!= null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    public void Logout(Activity activity){

        preferencesConfig.writeLoginStatus(false);
        preferencesConfig.writeUsername("Name");
        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class));
        activity.finish();
    }

}
```

**Car.java**

```
package com.example.smartparkingapp.Model;

public class Car {
    private String id;
    private String carPlate;

    public Car(){

    }

    public Car(String id, String carPlate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.carPlate = carPlate;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCarPlate() {
        return carPlate;
    }

    public void setCarPlate(String carPlate) {
        this.carPlate = carPlate;
    }
}
```

**AppController.java** *(my singleton)*

```
package com.example.smartparkingapp.app;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

**CarListAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.smartparkingapp.adapter;
public class CarListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<Car> carItems;

    public CarListAdapter(Fragment fragment, List<Car> carItems) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.carItems = carItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return carItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return carItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (layoutInflater == null)
            layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.car_layout_row, null);

        TextView idTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IdTextView);
        TextView numberPlatetextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plateNumberTextView);

        Car c = carItems.get(position);

        idTextView.setText(String.valueOf(c.getId()));
        numberPlatetextView.setText(c.getCarPlate());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for such a long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a null `activity` in your adapter. Pass the activity object into CarListAdapter constructor from your calling activity

Something like:
In your HomeFragment

`carListAdapter = new CarListAdapter(this, carList, getActivity());`

and in your CarListAdapter:

```
public class CarListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<Car> carItems;

    public CarListAdapter(Fragment fragment, List<Car> carItems, Activity activity) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.carItems = carItems;
        this.activity = activity;
    }
.....
```

This is according to the error you have shown

Comment: Oh no, how can I missed that.. Thank you very much @T.Mas . Now my project is working. How am I gonna show what I have done to my code? Should  I edit my post?

Comment: You are most welcome. You can leave your post as is. People will look at the problem you had and then look to the marked answer to know where the issue was

Comment: Ok I will leave as it be. However, I modified it by eliminate the fragment but add Activity in the constructor.